# Unity, setWindowsHook and multi-thread for frame independent input system on Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, multithreading, unity-game-engine

---

I want to achieve a frame independent touch input system In Unity to get touches events from Windows directly.

***What I have done is :***

=> Write a ***C++*** code to set up Windows Hook on Global [WM-Touch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wintouch/wm-touchdown) Message. (Using [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw), with thread Id = 0 for global message), compile it into a ***DLL***.

[Code based on this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/adding-multi-touch-support-to-unity-games-on-microsoft-windows-7-and-windows-8-desktop)

```
void DLL_initialize_hook(IntPtr window_handler)
{
    // <g_hInst> is the DLL handler
    // <HookProcPosted> and <HookProcCalled> are the functions
    // to filter and manage touch messages
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, (HOOKPROC)HookProcPosted, g_hInst, 0);
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)HookProcCalled, g_hInst, 0);

    //register touch window to receive touch data as WM-Touch
    int fine_touch = 1;
    RegisterTouchWindow(window_handler, fine_touch );
}
```

=> Create a ***DLL_Interface Singleton*** class using ***C#*** to encapsulate functions from the DLL.

```
void StartHook(IntPtr unity_window_handler )
{
  DLL_initialize_hook(unity_window_handler );
}

Touch[] getAllTouchData()
{
    //Actually there are more steps than just calling 2 function
    //that's why i wraped it
    TouchData[] data = DLL_getTouchData()
    return ConvertAllData(data );
}
```

=> Create a ***new thread*** (let's name it ***loop_thread***) in ***Unity*** using ***C#***, ***initialize the Hook in loop_thread*** using functions from the DLL compiled previously (the DLL initialize function requires the Unity window handler to register it as a touch window : [RegisterTouchWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow))

```
//the function to run in the thread
void Thread_run()
{
    Thread_Initialize();
    Thread_Loop();
}

void Thread_Initialize()
{
    DLL_Interface.StarHook(unity_window_handler);
}
```

=> The loop_thread pull the touch event at 250Hz from DLL (The DLL only output new Data)

```
void Thread_Loop()
{
    while(running)
    {
        //Get the Touche data using a function from singleton interface
        List<Touch> touches = DLL_Interface.Instance.getAllTouchData();

        //Conversion and put the data available for Unity in a thread safe way
        ManageTheTouches(touches);

        //Wait next pull
        Thread.sleep(sleep_time)
    }
}
```

---

What i want is to ***receive touch input without being limited by the Unity frame update rate***.

Even though i ***initialized a global hook*** for touch messages on ***loop_thread***, and pull the touch input with 250Hz as frequency, ***the touch input rate is still limited by Unity frame update rate***.

[Unity update rate is 30 Hz, touch input also limited at 30 Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBhla.png)

[Unity update rate is 60 Hz, touch input also limited at 60 Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PxmJ.png)

**Why the Hook initialized on loop_thread is limited by Unity's main thread's frame rate ?**

I have several suspects :

=>***RegisterTouchWindow*** function is waitting Unity's main thread's response before sending the WM-Touch message, that's why i can't bypass Unity's frame update rate using this function.

=>***SetWindowHookEx*** function somehow inject the code to filter messages into Unity's main thread, so it is limited by the Unity's main thread's frame rate.(In ***documentation*** it is stated out that : "the system executes the hook in the hooking app's context; specifically, on the thread that called SetWindowsHookEx")

=>Calling the hook initialize function from the DLL in loop_thread does not install the hook on the loop_thread, but on the caller's main thread(in this case, the Unity main thread?).